# UIWebView JavaScript troubles in iOS 5 (esp. window.pageYOffset and window.scrollTo)

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, ios5

This UIWebView code that worked fine under iOS 4 no longer works in iOS 5:

```
// webView is UIWebView loaded with a local PDF file
NString *s = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"];
```

The contents of s is always "0" regardless of the actual position of the webView.
and

```
// webPosition is the desired Y scroll position
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"window.scrollTo(0, %d);", webPosition]];
```

Any ideas on a workaround to position the webView and read the position that works in iOS 5?

Answer (score 4):

You can use UIWebView's Scrollview for navigation as Javascript is no more supported in IOS5: Below code worked fine for me.

```
    [aWebView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y)];
```

The contentOffset accepts a CGPoint as argument. Here x and y are integer values representing the scrollPosition. If you want to get current x and y co-ordinates for webView, below is the code which you can use:

```
NSInteger x = aWebview.scrollView.contentOffSet.x;
NSInteger y = aWebview.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

**Note:** ScrollView is introduced in IOS 5 and will not work on earlier IOS versions. Javascript function are available for earlier versions. So you can check for device version and implement code accordingly.

Comment: Hi Jeet, I just want to correct one thing. Javascript still runs; It's just that window.scrollTo() does not. I can confirm this because Javascript based text search still works for me even though Javascript based scrolling does not. Other than that, nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, from MRL at Apple:

> In iOS 5, we exposed the UIWebView's UIScrollView.  You'd be better
>   off just saving and restoring the contentOffset instead of trying to
>   do this through javascript.